# Should summed effective addresses 'wrap' in PowerPC? If so, how?

Tags: assembly, powerpc

For example, the PowerPC book I, section 3.3.2, defines the `lbz` instruction as:

> Let the effective address (EA) be the sum (RA|0)+ D. The byte in storage addressed by EA is loaded into RT<sub>56:63</sub>. RT<sub>0:55</sub> are set to 0.

What should I do in the following two situations?

- Should I wrap or do something when `(RA) + D > memory_capacity`?
- Should I wrap or do something when `(RA) + D > 4294967295`?

In other words, is the effective address just the sum of `(RA) + D`, or is the calculation done `mod memory_capacity` or `mod 2^32-1`?

Relevant practical material: every line that sets `var EA` in [this script](http://azabani.com/cgit.cgi/jsppc/plain/jsppc.js).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Power ISA 2.06 book, section 1.9.3 Effective Address Calculation

> In 32-bit mode, the low-order 32 bits of the 64-bit result,
>   preceded by 32 0 bits, comprise the 64-bit effective
>   address for the purpose of addressing storage. [...] As used to address storage, the
>   effective address arithmetic appears
>   to wrap around from the maximum
>   address, 2<sup>32</sup>-1, to address
>   0, except that if the current
>   instruction is at effective address
>   2<sup>32</sup>-4 the effective address
>   of the next sequential instruction is
>   undefined.

Comment: Am I interpreting this correctly if I implement this by applying `mod 4294967296` on all the values that I assign to the effective addresses?

Comment: X & 0xFFFFFFFF is easier and faster.